# User matching query does not exist error suddenly appeared in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Im having an error while im trying to view/create instances of my certain models in admin. Though manage.py shell all is working fine. 
I saw that there were some similar answers but I didn't manage to figure out the solution for my case out of them.
Here is the console trace back:
[image]

And its what i see in the browser:
[image]

So I basically have 2 questions:
1) how to fix it?
2) why this problem occurred and how to prevent it in future?

Thank you!

UPDATE:
Here is my code for one of the models that im having issues with:

```
class ProfileModel(models.Model):
    """
    Students Profile model
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

    is_student = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=u"Student",
        default=True,
    )

    is_professor = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=u"Professor",
        default=False,
        blank=True
    )

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name="Staff Member",
        default=False,
        blank=True
    )

    started_date = models.DateField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        verbose_name=u"Started Working/Studying"
    )

    faculty = models.ForeignKey(
        'department.FacultyModel',
        verbose_name=u"Faculty",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    department = models.ForeignKey(
        'department.DepartmentModel',
        verbose_name=u"Department",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    student_group = models.ForeignKey(
        'department.StudentGroupModel',
        verbose_name=u"Group",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    middle_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=u"Middle Name",
        default='')

    birthday = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=u"Date of Birth",
        null=True)

    contact_phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=55,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=u"Contact Phone",
        null=True,
    )

    photo = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=u"Photo",
        null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.is_student:
            return u"Student: %s" % self.user.get_full_name()
        elif self.is_professor:
            return u"Professor: %s" % self.user.get_full_name()
        else:
            return u"Staff Member: %s" % self.user.get_full_name()
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Ok, so I think that i now what might be the issue. I have ProfileModel that extends Django User model and it appears that i have more profilemodel instances than User instances. At the moment i have only one user with flag is_student eqals to True; however the API is still working and if I request list of all students i would get 7 instances(1 the i have in Users tab in admin and 6 that were deleted previously with null values on the fields that belongs to the user model). Alos if I run the ProfileModel.objects.filter(is_student=True) i would get the same error as you see above. Which force me to the conclusion that Profile model instance is not being deleted when im deleting a user instance  in admin. Can it be the issue and if so - then how can i fix it?

Comment: Please share your code? You are trying to find out user in database but user not present in database so the error is raised.

Comment: I've added the piece of code for the problematic model; Yes, I got that something goes wrong when its trying to get the user id, but the user IS in the database;

Comment: The model code you have posted isn't where the error happens. It happens in a model that has `"Student: "...` in the `__unicode__` method (possibly your profile model - if so post the code for that model). That model has a `user` field. Also, please don't post screenshots of the error. Instead paste the text version.

Comment: Updated post with the ProfileModel code